# Eclipse saves configuration even when removed

Tags: eclipse, configuration, uninstallation, eclipse-juno

I'm in trouble with Eclipse configuration. I had Eclipse Juno with a certain configuration (perspectives, opened views like Logcat, console, etc), I removed it from my system and downloaded Eclipse Luna.

When I opened it the first time and selected the Workspace, Eclipse loaded the perspectives used in Juno (for example Remote System Explorer) but those perspectives weren't installed in Eclipse.
This also happens with the Logcat view, Eclipse Luna hasn't installed ADT (Android) and Logcat wasn't available.

Why is this configuration loaded if I removed Eclipse completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workspace contains the information about the perspectives, views, ... in use.

So if you install a version of Eclipse without some of the plugins you were previously using you should probably create a new workspace. You can import your projects from the old workspace (but if the projects reference any of the old plugins you may get errors).